# Regex to get the entire string after last occurrence of "#" in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

Hello I am new to using Regex. I have this following string -

```
##H2\n\ncontent.\n\n## Headers\n\nTEST\n\n# H1 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n# H2 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n### H3 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n#### H4 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n##### H5 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n###### H6 - Create the best documentation\n\n
```

I have written an [expression](https://regex101.com/r/oGaYF0/1) to find the last occurrence of "#". After I get the last #, then from there I want to take the entire string until only first \n is found.

So for example when I find last "#" in #####***#*** H6 - Create the best documentation\n\n  . Then the want to extract **# H6 - Create the best documentation**

Is there a way I can do this with regex? I am using this inside a JavaScript code, so is it possible to do this with regex ?

Comment: What is the actual output you expect based on the string in your question above?

Comment: Hi I have updated the question. Can you please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let myRegex = new RegExp(/^[^]*(#[^]*)$/);
let matches = myRegex.exec("%sdfsdf#\n##sdgsdf\ngdf#sadgofofo#jhjhj\nhjh");
let myResult = matches[1]
```

The pattern break down is this:

```
'^' start at the beginning of the string
'[^]*' match everything including line breaks as much as you can including any '#'
'(#[^]*)' group a match of the final '#' and anything following it, including line breaks
'$' to the end of the string
```

Regex is greedy so it will suck up everything and land on the final '#' using the pattern above.
The '[^]' is used to match on line breaks.
I learned that from the MDN site examples here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Here is a wonderful regular expression testing site if you have not found it yet:

https://regex101.com/

Here is a JS Fiddle of the above solution
https://jsfiddle.net/y8qbe705/

Comment: Hey buddy. Appreciate for your help but I have json file with other cases as well. For this case here:  https://jsfiddle.net/djq5v74k/5/  it does not work :(

Comment: Looking at the fiddle, it is doing exactly what your question said you wanted. To capture the final hashmark and all the rest of the content that comes after it. Clarify what you need for that particular case.

Comment: Oh wait I re-read what you wanted. You want just to the occurrence of the \n.  Gimme a minute to fix that.

Comment: There you go. I fixed it.  https://jsfiddle.net/vucqbg0j/

Comment: This is awesome sir ! Thank you so much. Just a last request that if I remove \n from my string and if I have a string like this without \n - https://jsfiddle.net/oz8g52sf/1/ . Then is it possible to find # Markdown Syntax in this example https://jsfiddle.net/oz8g52sf/1/ . I am asking this because I have a JSON file in my JavaScript code from where I am getting the string which has \n. But I may to remove the \n

Comment: Something like this maybe  https://jsfiddle.net/6bx7prdg/1/

Comment: YES ! You're awesome !. If time permits then can you please explain the Regex, like how it is working?

Comment: My assumption is the final hashmark will be followed by a series of words that have just a single space in front of each word.  So I am looking for groups of '\s' space and then '\w+' word.  I expect one or more of them (\s\w+)+  so I keep collecting that pattern until it is broken by a series of what I expect to be a bunch of spaces strung together.

Comment: Thanks ! You're a saviour. Appreciate the help :)

Comment: Hey just wanted to know if we can remove the # from the output from your code jsfiddle.net/ke4Lw60s I did it with replace method but can you please do it using Regex? The logic remains the same, I just want to remove the # from the output in your code using Regex.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(#[^#]*)$
```

Example:

```
"##H2\n\ncontent.\n\n## Headers\n\nTEST\n\n# H1 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n# H2 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n### H3 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n#### H4 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n##### H5 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n###### H6 - Create the best documentation\n\n".match(/(#[^#]*)$/)

// ouput: [ "# H6 - Create the best documentation\n\n", "# H6 - Create the best documentation\n\n" ]
```

Trimmed example

```
const trimmed = "##H2\n\ncontent.\n\n## Headers\n\nTEST\n\n# H1 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n# H2 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n### H3 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n#### H4 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n##### H5 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n###### H6 - Create the best documentation\n\n".match(/(#[^#]*)$/).pop().replace(/\s*$/, "")

// "# H6 - Create the best documentation"
```

Limit the output till first line break example:

```
const trimmed2 = "##H2\n\ncontent.\n\n## Headers\n\nTEST\n\n# H1 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n# H2 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n### H3 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n#### H4 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n##### H5 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n###### H6 - Create the best documentation\n\nnext line"
.match(/(#[^#]*)$/)
.pop()
.replace(/(?:\n+.*)?$/, "")

// "# H6 - Create the best documentation"
```

Comment: Thanks it works but can you please give an expression which will just extract:  # H6 - Create the best documentation. 
With your current expression it will take everything until end of string. My case I just want the string until last occurrence of # is found to the first occurrence of \n. So final desired output should be -  # H6 - Create the best documentation

Comment: @GurbazPooran no worries, please see edit for trimmed string output

Comment: Hey thanks but it is failing for some cases. If u run on the following string, it does not work

`const trimmed = "## Markdown Syntax\n\nTo serve as an example page when styling markdown based Docusaurus sites.\nYou can write content using".match(/(#[^#]*)$/).pop().replace(/\s*$/, "") `        



// "# Markdown Syntax To serve as an example page when styling markdown based Docusaurus sites.
You can write content using "


Desired output should be: " # Markdown Syntax "

Comment: @GurbazPooran no worries, we'll get it right sooner or later =) see edit trimmed2, for limiting the output from last # untill end of the line

Answer (score 0):

**[`(?:#[^#\\]+(?!.*#))`](https://regex101.com/r/qNC9SJ/1)**

Match from `#` but not any more of `#` or `\` and it should be last one matches `#`. It is not the best solution, but works!. Output.

```
# H6 - Create the best documentation
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use  a regex replacement here:

```js
var input = "##H2\n\ncontent.\n\n## Headers\n\nTEST\n\n# H1 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n# H2 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n### H3 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n#### H4 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n##### H5 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n###### H6 - Create the best documentation\n\n";
var output = input.replace(/^.*(#.*?)(?=\n|$)/s, "$1");
console.log(output);
```

The regex replacement strips off all content up to, but not including, the last `#` sign.  Then we match and capture all proceeding content up to, but not including, the nearest newline.

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```regex
^             from the start of the string
    .*        consume all content until the LAST
    (#.*?)    # followed by all content up to the first (capture in $1)
    (?=\n|$)  newline character or the end of the input
```

Then, we replace with just the capture hashtag, which is in `$1`.

Comment: Hey thanks. Can you please explain your regular expression - (/^.*(#.*?)(?=\n|$)/s)

Comment: @GurbazPooran Check the updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Match the string that starts with a `#` character, and terminates at the end of the string, and has non `#` characters in between ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TPjcuv/1)):

```js
const input = "##H2\n\ncontent.\n\n## Headers\n\nTEST\n\n# H1 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n# H2 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n### H3 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n#### H4 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n##### H5 - Create the best documentation\n\nTEST\n\n###### H6 - Create the best documentation\n\n";

const output = input.match(/#[^#]+$/s);

console.log(output);
```